# MPI: send a vector differently populated in each rank to all other ranks

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I want to communicate data living in a process to all processes, for each process in the MPI pool.

Schematically, in pseudocode:

```
int main() {

    MPI_Init();

    vector = new empty vector of length N_PROCS;
    
    populate_vector_with_data_from_this_rank(vector);

    // vector now has its elements' locations dictating 
    // which process that particular element has to arrive at.

    // that is, 0-th element has to arrive at rank 0, 1-st element has to arrive at rank 1, etc ...

    MPI_Scatter(vector, root = rank, ...);

    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

How could I achieve this?

The vector `vector` is populated differently inside each rank and has to be distributed to all ranks after it's been populated.

Basically, each rank has to talk to each rank in my scheme.

Thank you!

Comment: What you want is `MP_Alltoall`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, thank you. I didn't know about this command. I will read about it.

Comment: (and of course you note my typo: it's `MPI_Alltoall`, not `MP_Alltoall`.) (and I just put this into ChatGPT which suggested `MPI_Allgather`, which is wrong.)

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, yes, I noticed the typo, no worries. I have had ChatGPT telling me wrongly how to profile a code with ``gprof``, and after that I resigned using it ...